# Configurar IPv4 para SERVER y CLIENTE en Windows Server (Active Directory) (Máquinas Virtuales en Hyper-V)

Tags: dns, activedirectory, windows-server-2016

Me estoy volviendo loco, tratando de añadir un cliente a un dominio creado en Windows Server (todo máquinas virtuales, en Hyper-V).

La cuestión es que cada vez que quiero añadir el ordenador cliente al dominio, me dice que hay un problema con las DNS.
Máquina Virtual del Servidor y del Cliente están configuradas con conmutador interno (para red LAN).
De tal modo, la configuración del ordenador SERVER es la siguiente (sí, está en inglés):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por su parte, la configuración del ordenador CLIENTE es la siguiente (sí, está en francés):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y SIEMPRE, siempre, me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al cliente no le puedes asignar la misma IP que el servidor, prueba con estos valores: Addresse: 169.254.236.164 Masque: 255.255.0.0 Passarelle: 169.254.236.163  DNS prefere: 169.254.236.163  DNS aux: 8.8.8.8.  Aunque la recomendación es usar DHCP en lugar de IPs estáticas para los clientes.

Comment: Hola Sal, qué tal? Gracias, intenté lo que dijiste, pero es imposible. Hay algo que se me escapa. Creo que la clave (que no entiendo) es la IP del cliente, que entiendo que tiene que estar dentro del rango de IPs del servidor (IP que luego tiene que estar establecida como DNS de preferencia). Trato de hacer esto en Hyper-V, con dos switch virtuales internos, en plan LAN.
Así llevo bloqueado...semanas.‍♂️